# Downgrading R version

Tags: rhel5, downgrade

I have R version 2.10 installed (from an RPM) on a RHEL 5 machine.  What would be the easiest way to downgrade to version 2.8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the RPM file and do

```
rpm -Uvh --oldpackage r-package-file-2.08.architecture.rpm
```

There may be endless complications if the older package is for an earlier distro and has (ugh!) *dependencies*, but as long as it's just an earlier version for RHEL5, you should be OK.